# Pages - multiple paragraph styles in a single paragraph

Tags: mac, pages, formatting

I'm trying to write code snippets inline with prose text, much like the ``` back ticks (``) in markdown ``` in Pages (`version 5.6.1`). I have a "code" paragraph style, and a "body" paragraph style. Is there a way to intermix the two on the same line/paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a *character* style for **code**, and then perhaps use a *"code block"* paragraph style for code blocks that are, well, paragraphs. Think about this: if the code paragraph style is double spaced and your prose paragraph style is 1.5 spaced, which one "wins" when the break is mid-line?

### To add a new Character Style in pages

(from https://help.apple.com/pages/mac/5.6/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/tan7aaef6765)

> Select the character with the formatting you want to save as a style.
>
> Click the Style button near the top of the sidebar on the right.
>
> If you don’t see a sidebar, or the sidebar doesn’t have a Style button, click Format button in the toolbar. If the text is in a text box, table, or shape, first click the Text tab at the top of the sidebar, then click the Style button.
>
> In the Font section, click the pop-up menu next to Character Styles, then do one of the following:
>
> 1. Create a new style with a new name: Click New style button in the top-right corner of the Character Styles menu, then type a name for the style.
> 2. Create a new style based on an existing style: Move the pointer over the style name in the list, click the arrow that appears, then choose Redefine from Selection (characters that used the original style aren’t changed).
>
> Type a name for the style.

Comment: Where do you set these "character styles"? I can't find any such thing

Comment: It was less obvious than I remembered! I edited my answer to include instructions.

Comment: Wow, it's only 3 lines down from the Paragraph Style selection menu... Don't know how I missed that!